# Raspberry Pi 2 GPSD Not Running

Tags: raspberry-pi2, gpsd

I am following [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps-on-the-raspberry-pi?view=all) tutorial to hook up Adafruit's Ultimate GPS Breakout to my Raspberry Pi 2. I have carefully read each step.

When I run `gpsmon /dev/ttyUSB0`, it displays expected output with my location, speed, etc. When I run `cgps -s`, however, I get this message `cgps: no gpsd running or network error: -4, can't create socket`.

The really weird thing is that the GPSD seems to be failing. Here is me trying to start it:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo service gpsd status
[FAIL] gpsd is not running ... failed!
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo service gpsd restart
[ ok ] Restarting GPS (Global Positioning System) daemon: gpsd.
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo service gpsd status
[FAIL] gpsd is not running ... failed!
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo service gpsd start
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo service gpsd status
[FAIL] gpsd is not running ... failed!
```

So, it is apparent that `cgps` is failing because GPSD is not starter. Any suggestions to get GPSD working?

**EDIT**
When I run `sudo gpsd -N -D3 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock`, I get this output:

```
gpsd:INFO: launching (Version 3.6)
gpsd:ERROR: can't bind to IPv4 port gpsd, Cannot assign requested address
gpsd:ERROR: can't create IPv6 socket
gpsd:DATA: command sockets creation failed, netlib errors -1, -1
```

Comment: Try running gpsd as an executable rather than as a service and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer. However I just bumped into this problem and found that my `/etc/network/interfaces` didn't exist. Thusly there was no `loopback` interface present. If `interfaces` doesn't exist, try creating it by running `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` and add:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

(Or as it suits your setup.)

Then run `ifup -a` and check if there's a new interface by running `ifconfig`. It should be somewhat like:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:16:bc:52
[...]

lo       Link encap:Local Loopback
[...]
```

Hope it works for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

For unrelated reasons, I reimaged my Pi, and the gps module is now working as expected. I don't know what was wrong last time, but it is working now.